# Fastest Math.Max(value,0)

Tags: c#, performance

I have an algorithm which does lot of comparisons of floats/doubles to 0.

Something like that:

```
var sum = 0.0;
for(int i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
  sum += Math.Max(data[i],0);
```

I was wondering if there is any faster way to do this?
This performs barely faster (5-7%) on my micro-benchmark.

```
public static unsafe float FasterCompare(float value)
{
  var val = *(int*) &value;
  return val > 0 ? value : 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a major performance bottleneck that requires being optimized?

Comment: what does `data` look like..?

Comment: And how much does that 5-7% improvement affect _overall_ performance?

Comment: @Servy It isn't actually a major bottleneck. Minor one at best. But I was curious it was possible to speed it up

Comment: @Michal Then it sounds like your time would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs see line 441 for Math.Max, its not overly complicated but if you can guarentee that none of the values are ever `Single.Nan`, then you can remove one check by writing your own. Boils down to  sum += (data[i] > 0.0f ? data[i] : 0.0f). Also remove the implicit conversions since that costs something, declare `sum` as `float` or `double` based on the array, right now you are summing floats, converting ints, and converting again to double...

Comment: What are you trying to do here at all?  You add any value from data that's greater or equal to zero to the sum.  Why even do `Math.Max()`?  You can just check if the value is >= 0 and add it.

Comment: @B.K. My code is actually doing: sum += data[i] > 0 ? data[i] : 0;

Comment: There's something seriously wrong with your benchmark, there always is, the cost of this code is reading the array element, *not* the comparison.  Accessing memory is by far the most expensive thing a processor ever does.  The comparison is for free, then the processor just stalls waiting for the value.

Comment: @Michal Actually, your code is doing `sum += data[i] > 0 ? data[i] : Double.IsNaN(data[i]) ? data[i] : 0;`  http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,c2b57dc2156f32d4

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is this:

```
var sum = 0.0;
for(int i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
  sum += Math.Max(data[i],0);
```

`Math.Max` is doing this:

```
public static double Max(double val1, double val2) 
{
    if (val1 > val2)
        return val1;

    if (Double.IsNaN(val1))
        return val1;

    return val2;
}
```

If you know that you're not going to have `NaN`, implement your own `Max` without the `NaN` check:

```
public static double Max(double val1, double val2) 
{
    if (val1 > val2)
        return val1;

    return val2;
}
```

Comment: This is what I actually have in my real code. I should have specified.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a small benchmark, here are my results:

> Your version: ~2.3ms
>
> Optimized version: ~1.4ms

Here is the code:

```
float[] data = new float[150000];
Random rnd = new Random(12345);

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = (float)(rnd.NextDouble() * 5000.0 - 2500.0);
}

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();

var varsum = 0.0;  //varsum is a DOUBLE!!!!

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    varsum += Math.Max(data[i], 0);        //implicit conversions, float->double, int->float

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Varsum : " + varsum);

Console.WriteLine("Time it took for the original: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");
   
float floatsum = 0.0f;
    
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();

floatsum = 0.0f;

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    if (data[i] > 0.0f)
        floatsum += data[i];

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("OptimizedSum: " + floatsum);

Console.WriteLine("Time it took for \"optimized\" version: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");

//Equality on floating point numbers doesn't work like this, but...
Console.WriteLine("Are these two equal? " + (floatsum == varsum).ToString());
Console.WriteLine("How close are they? " + Math.Abs(floatsum - varsum).ToString("00.0000000000000000"));

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Console application, 32-bit process, running debug mode, compiled for AnyCPU. The second version is around 60% faster. This is probably due to not having to call into a method that can't be inlined.

It should also be noted that **these two methods do not return the same value**. That is because a `double` and a `float` do not have the same precision. If you are working with floats, stay with floats. Same with double, don't convert back and forth. The example above gave me a difference of over 65!

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S5qmCg (fiddle version doesn't reflect same time values above, I'm assuming because its resource limited on the server side, so try on your own computer)

Comment: I'm seeing less disparity, but I can confirm that optimized version is running faster on my machine on average by 15-20% faster.

Comment: Adding it into a loop that runs 10 times (as an example) lets the JIT optimize, try putting the  code in its own method and call it a few times.

Comment: I just used your code completely.  Don't want to invest any more time into this pointless optimization that he's trying to do.  It's not like we're talking O(nlogn) or O(n^2) here, it's just O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how large your array is (and your machine).  This is significantly faster on my machine depending on the size of the array:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float[] data = new float[1500000];
        Random rnd = new Random(12345);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (float)(rnd.NextDouble() * 5000.0 - 2500.0);
        }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        var varsum = 0.0f;  //varsum is a DOUBLE!!!! change this to 0.0f to make them equal!

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            varsum += Math.Max(data[i], 0);        //implicit conversions, float->double, int->float

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Varsum : " + varsum);

        Console.WriteLine("Time it took for the original: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");

        float floatsum = 0.0f;

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        floatsum = 0.0f;
        floatsum=data.AsParallel().Where(d=>d>0).Sum();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("OptimizedSum: " + floatsum);

        Console.WriteLine("Time it took for \"optimized\" version: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms");

        //Equality on floating point numbers doesn't work like this, but...
        Console.WriteLine("Are these two equal? " + (floatsum == varsum).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("How close are they? " + Math.Abs(floatsum - varsum).ToString("00.0000000000000000"));

    }
}
```